# Removing square brackets

Tags: python, json, pandas, mongodb

I'm trying to convert some data from CSV to JSON, in preparation for loading into MongoDB as documents. I have browsed hundreds of Q&As and come up with the below code, but there is an issue with the square brackets being added.

The structure I need is as follows, for all UK postcodes:

```
[
   {
      "Postcode":"BS273EE",
      "Location":
         {
            "coordinates":[
               "-2.783927",
               "51.275287"]
            ,
            "type":"Point"
         }
      ]
   }]
```

I am getting the following though - just the square brackets in the location element, for the list of one dict:

```
[
   {
      "Postcode":"BS273EE",
      "Location":[
         {
            "coordinates":[
               "-2.783927",
               "51.275287"]
            ,
            "type":"Point"
         }
      ]
   }]
```

The code I am using is:

```
url = 'National_Statistics_Postcode_Lookup_UK_Coordinates.csv'
fields= ['Postcode 1', 'Longitude','Latitude']
df = pd.read_csv(url, skipinitialspace=True,usecols=fields,dtype=str)
df['type'] = 'Point'
df['coordinates'] = df[["Longitude","Latitude"]].values.tolist()
df1 = df[['Postcode','type','coordinates']]
df2 = (df1.head(5).groupby(['Postcode']).apply(lambda x: x[{'type','coordinates'}].to_dict('records')).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Location'}).to_json(orient='records'))
print(df2)#testing output
```

The original CSV data structure is just:

```
Postcode, Longitude, Latitude

XX56XX     -95.4343   55.5335
```

I have found that changing the to_dict to 'index' does what I need, but then the word 'Location' is replaced with iterating numbers for each of the 100,000 or so postcodes. I need the word 'Location' there, not the number "0", "1", etc.. So changing the `to_dict('records')` to `to_dict('index')` is not the right answer.

Comment: Your "needed structure" is invalid.  There are 2 [ and 3 ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting to records, add `[0]` to get the first element:

```py
result = (
    df1.head(5)
    .groupby(["Postcode"])
    # Following line is changed
    .apply(lambda x: x[["type", "coordinates"]].to_dict("records")[0]) 
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "Location"})
).to_json(orient="records")
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "Postcode":"BS273EE",
        "Location":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
                "-2.783927",
                "51.275287"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: lol, why don't you break up that one-liner and also highlight where you added the `[0]` with a comment?

Comment: The one-liner was taken from the original question. I have edited my answer with propper formatting.

Comment: I see an unmatched `]` in your output.

Comment: @MarGenDo - Thank you SO SO much. I've been trying to do this for nearly 3 days. I'm so darn grateful for your help and really glad it was such a simple solution! Thanks again and have a great day!!